# how to return a specific set of data from multiple columns in a database in sql

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and this is my first ever question. I am working with a sample database that I want to extract specific information from to display as a dashboard. The issue is that I can do this partially but I cannot seem to figure it out properly.

```
``SELECT 
S_date as date,
p_time as time,
process_id as process, 
sc_gun as scannumb, 
sum(line_qty) as linetotal,
sum(area_qty) as areatotal

FROM dbfile6
WHERE 
  process_id in('0010','0020','0030')
and sc_gun in = ('10','20','30','40','50')
and s_date = curdate() - 1 and p_time between '22:00:00' and '23:59:59'
or s_date = curdate() and p_time between '00:00:00' and '06:00:00'
GROUP BY p_time, s_date, process_id, sc_gun
ORDER BY s_date, process_id
```

**What do I want to display?**
I can do partially where I want it to work to yesterdays date (s_date) recurring but I want this to only happen Monday to Friday, skipping the weekend so when we are on Monday, it looks at Fridays data from the database.

I want to show the time as a range, a night range. The range is 20:00:00 - 06:00:00. The range is tricky as it crosses over to the next day, this could work for Monday to Thursday but not Friday as there is no working weekend so what would I do here? In addition to this, I can sum up the values successfully and display it as averages for each process but then once I add the time in, it displays each result individually.

The table below is what it looks like in the database, however as mentioned earlier, the desired result is for each process to have the line_qty and area_qty summed up by time range and a day and night cycle.

| s_date | p_time | process_id | sc_gun | line_qty | area_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/05/2022 | 04:49:52 | 0010 | 10 | 2 | 12 |
| 03/05/2022 | 11:50:00 | 0010 | 10 | 5 | 14 |
| 03/05/2022 | 19:50:00 | 0010 | 10 | 7 | 16 |
| 03/05/2022 | 13:50:00 | 0020 | 20 | 4 | 6 |
| 03/05/2022 | 19:50:00 | 0010 | 10 | 7 | 16 |

Comment: You should provide an example dataset and result as well as the expected result, otherwise, it's very difficult to understand what you have versus what you want.

Comment: I have added a table, this is very similar to what the actual output is. If I removed the p_time from the sql query, it actually sums up each process so all the 0010 into one, and the 0020 into one. I don't know why it doesn't do this when I add the time

Comment: I think one place to start is your `WHERE` clause. You have `or` interspersed with `and` without any parenthesis to indicate precedence. Also, with that in mind, `p_time between '22:00:00' and '23:59:59'` will generate no results with the dataset you've given, so it's moot or you should include data for it. Also, example queries and expected results, please; it's just much easier for me to see a path with more info.